# CppFlow on windows 10

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I found this interesting project on Github (https://github.com/serizba/cppflow) 
Which is a c++ wrapper for the tensor api written in C.

However I have some issues when installing it..

I have installed a c++ compiler, but when I try to build it in visual studio, I get the following error:

cannot convert from 'T *' to 'std::vector>'

Does anybody have experience with this wrapper or recogninces the error message? My initial though was that I am using the wrong c++ compilier.

Comment: Impossible to diagnose the compiler error message without knowing what line of code it relates to.

Comment: I see from the project that it requires C++17. Have you enabled C++17 in your visual studio compilation?

Comment: Where did you see that? Anyhow thanks! (from the syntax or something?)

Comment: I have enabled c++17 under the project settings (ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17)). However when I debug I use "Local Windows debugger" I only assume that is c++17 since the project is defined for 17?

Comment: "return { T_data, T_data + size };" Gives two error messages:

1: Conversion from 'T *const ' to 'bool' requires a narrowing conversion.
2: Conversion from 'T *' to 'bool' requires a narrowing conversion.

Comment: I saw the setting in this file https://github.com/serizba/cppflow/blob/master/examples/load_model/CMakeLists.txt (line 4).

Comment: `/std:c++17` is the setting you (apparently) need.

Comment: Which is the same that I got, but I still get the errors..

Comment: Which source file does that line appear in? Just quoting one line is not enough context to understand the error.

Comment: Tensor.cpp (line 146). But the template function is used on 208 (the one that causes the issue). When I comment that one, I get several other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm not enough of a language lawyer to know where the fault lies (the code or the compiler) but it's clear that the intent of the line of code causing the problems is this

```
return std::vector<T>(T_data, T_data + size);
```

With that more old-fashioned style of code it compiles for me.

Comment: Hmm, that error was removed, however I got some others. Where did you put the tensorflow folder?

Comment: @AtleKristiansen That's a different topic, so if you need help create a new question. I just editted the `#include` directives until it compiled. But obviously you should do the right thing and edit your project settings to reflect the location of your tensorflow folder. It shouldn't matter where you put it, the important thing is to tell your compiler where you put it.

Comment: Did you make it run on Windows? If so, can you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56798707/unable-to-compile-c-with-external-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, i found that the bool type doesn't seem to work for the moment. Take a look to the bottom of Tensor.cpp, and check that all the template with bool type are commented.