# Unable to compile c++ with external dependencies

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I have downloaded a c++ wrapper for the tensorflow API from the following link https://github.com/serizba/cppflow.

I have performed the following steps.

1. Cloned the Git repository.
2. Downloaded the Tensorflow API files 
   (https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-cpu-windows-x86_64-1.13.1.zip)
3. Extracted the files into the folder created from the Git clone.
4. Followed the "How to run it example provided on Github
5. CD to examples/load_model/, mkdir build, cd build, cmake ..
6. Here is where the troubles start, I am not able to run "make ." (says that it is nothing to run)
7. When I open the project created from cmake (visual studio 2019), I get linking issues, which I think is related to this CmakeLists.txt.

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
    project(example)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
    add_executable(example main.cpp ../../src/Model.cpp ../../src/Tensor.cpp)
    target_include_directories(example PRIVATE ../../include)
    target_link_libraries (example -ltensorflow)
```

More specifically the last line, the reason for this is that Visual Studio gives this warning "
Warning LNK4044 unrecognized option '/ltensorflow'; ignored example A:*\cppflow\examples\load_model\build\LINK 1   "

Can any one explain to my why this is a invalid option? Is it because it does not find the file in question?

Comment: `/ltensorflow` ooks a lot like one of the options got screwed up and is trying to use `-ltensorflow` like you would on a GCC-based compiler. My visual studio and cmake are too weak to tell you how to fix this.